# Как передать данные товара с главной страницы на шаблонную с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Уважаемые знатоки. Многие из вас пользуются интернет магазинами. При выборе товара на главной странице открывается его характеристики на шаблонной. Как реализовать этот функционал корректно? Как правильно передавать такие данные и каким способом (ajax, fetch)? Только начал разбираться с этим и толковой информации не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, необходимо при наведении на товар показать его характеристики. Если так, то:
-> слушатель на родительский элемент с уточнением класса товара 
-> ajax запрос на сервер (получаем JSON) 
-> в колбеке ajax реализуем формирование всплывающего окна с данными, оформленными как вам требуется (данные можно закешировать в JS, сохранив в обект с ID e.g. {89:{title:...}})
-> добавляем слушатель для скрытия окна.
Это один из множества реализаций.